# Jquery variable within quotes returning Syntax Error

Tags: jquery, variables, syntax, syntax-error, quotes

I am really confused with the simplest thing. Can anyone please help me on this one?

I've got the following code:

```
$('#nav a').click(function(){
    var $href = $(this).attr('href');

    if(!$($href).hasClass('top')){
          console.log("'#" + $href + "'");
    }
});
```

And it logs this every time I "click" on an link within "#nav":

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Any clues?

Thanks ;)

Comment: I think the problem is this `$($href)`

Comment: what is the value if $href? log it before the if statement

Comment: The value of the $href is an ID, can be #page or anything like it.

I tried logging it before the if statement and it now returns the log and the Error... strange

Comment: Very strange, probably a connection error with the Jquery online file, I have now tested the following (practically the same thing in question in this post) and it returns nicely with no errors :)

$('#navigation a').click(function(){
   var $href = $(this).attr('href');
   console.log("'"+$href+"'");                 

   if(!$($href).hasClass('top')){
      $($href).addClass('top');
   }
});

Comment: I'd recommend NOT prefixing your href variable with $ in this case. That's typically reserved for jQuery objects. Like, `var $div = $('#my-div'). In this case, it's not a jQuery object; it's a string. (Not to mention it makes $($href) look crazy.)

Comment: yeah, you are right, I will tidy things up once it's finished ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
console.log("'#" + $href + "'");
```

suggests to me that your href is something like 'page' and you are now prefixing it with '#'. If that's the case, then the previous selector

```
if(!$($href).hasClass('top'))
```

won't work because you're essentially doing

```
if (!$('page').hasClass('top'))
```

and 'page' is not a valid selector. Your href would need to be '#page'. Also, if the href doesn't have the #, I would think your browser would interpret that as a an actual URL to try to hit.

If this is not the case, a little more context would be helpful. What is supposed to happen? What are you trying to do?